# AngularJS | orderBy filter not updated dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble with the `orderBy` filter in AngularJS. Here's my setup:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in listItems.data | orderBy:order">
    <a ng-click="getRelated(item._id)">{{ item.title }}</a>
</li>
```

Part of the controller:

```
$scope.order = 'year';

$scope.listItems = $http.post($scope.url, {'filterType': 'abc', 'letter': $scope.params.letter});

$scope.setOrder = function(order) {
    $scope.order = order;
}
```

And finally the "switches" I would like to use for ordering the data

```
    <span class="sort--title">Sort by</span>
    <a ng-class="{true:'selected', false:''}[order=='title']" href="" ng-click="setOrder('title')" class="sort--attribute">Title</a>
    <a ng-class="{true:'selected', false:''}[order=='year']" href="" ng-click="setOrder('year')" class="sort--attribute">Year</a>
    <a ng-class="{true:'selected', false:''}[order=='length']" href="" ng-click="setOrder('length')" class="sort--attribute">Length</a>
    <a ng-class="{true:'selected', false:''}[order=='date_added']" href="" ng-click="setOrder('date_added')" class="sort--attribute">Date Added</a>
```

When I click the buttons, the list is not being re-ordered.
**When I manually change the initial `$scope.order` value, the list is ordered by the property. Also `ng-class` is updated correctly. I'm obviously missing out something!**

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle of your problem? I can't see what the data returned by your post function looks like.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the data is relevant in this case. My question basically is, how to make the `ng-repeat` data force to reload when the orderBy parameter changes. Or is this somehow related to the data?

Comment: It seems right to me. I think you should try to setup a jsFiddle. I think maybe some other things go wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think your idea is wrong. It does work. Here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fMrhagVKl2nehzTOHriF).

You must have something wrong somewhere else.

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('ngApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.friends = [
        {name: 'John', phone: '555-1276'},
        {name: 'Mary', phone: '800-BIG-MARY'},
        {name: 'Mike', phone: '555-4321'},
        {name: 'Adam', phone: '555-5678'},
        {name: 'Julie', phone: '555-8765'}
    ];
    $scope.setOrder = function (order) {
        $scope.order = order;
    };
}]);
```

main html

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li ng-class="{'active': order=='name'}"><a href="#" ng-click="setOrder('name')">name</a></li>
    <li  ng-class="{'active': order=='phone'}"><a href="#" ng-click="setOrder('phone')">phone</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="friend in friends|orderBy:order">
        <span class="name">{{friend.name}}</span>
        <span class="phone">{{friend.phone}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have found out, what was causing the problem. My what-I-thaught-to-be default setting of `order` var in the beginning of the controller: `$scope.order = 'year';` I compared your code to mine and that was the only difference, and removing it helped. I don't understand though, why is setting a variable this way causing the effect... I'm gonna accept your answer anyway, it helped me find the bug.

Comment: Well, I don't think that matter. You can try to do that in my code too. You can try  `$scope.order = 'name';` But thanks for accepting my answer. I'm glad I can help.

Comment: it actually matters, and I've encountered it again, and asked another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14075741/angularjs-scope-updates-not-reflected-in-the-view This was the case also with the `$scope.order` and I have no idea currently why is it so :)

Comment: Do you try it in my plunker ?

Comment: yes, also in a separate fiddle, and it works.. that's why I'm confused.. I described the problem more deeply in my linked question.. I got already one answer, but I'm too tired now, will try that tomorrow, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Cool, because I am kinda confused why you have that issue as well. I think there must be other stuff that cause that problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know its an old question but anyone else having the same issue might find this useful.
I had the same issue. Clicks to anchor were reloading the page and hence, the order was being set to default whenever you click any table header. This also explains why not setting the order to a default globally fixed it for you.

I replaced my anchor with a span element and it worked fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13096361)

Comment: I believe this provides an exact explanation to what the asker is confused about. There is an assumption I have made that the asker's page was also reloading but its a safe assumption since clicks on anchor are supposed to reload the page.