# Sorting array in asc desc

Tags: angularjs, sorting, select

I am new to angularjs here is my code i want to get data from url and also sort it by dynamically by selecting an item from select element but could't get the required result please help me out

**Html**

```
 <tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy: sortBy ">
      <td><a ng-href="{{ x.data.url}}">{{x.data.title}}</a>
      </td>
      <td>{{x.data.score}}</td>
 </tr>
```

**Code**

```
 $scope.$watch(function () {
     return $scope.sortExpression
 }, function (newSort) {
     $scope.sortBy = 'data.' + $scope.sortExpression
 })

 $http.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/new.json")
     .success(function (response) {
     $scope.names = response.data.children
 })
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g4ffa45g/)

Comment: what's wrong with his fiddle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011971/angularjs-orderby-filter-not-updated-dynamically

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar in sorting i get till now only sort byu asc order i need also by desc when it select from dropdown select element score desc or title desc

Comment: you want to control the sort direction?

Comment: @Jossef Harush just want to sort both ways like for options i have i dropdown sort by title asc,title DESC,Score ASC,Score DESC if option selected is with desc then sort by desc order if asc then so

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jme11/g4ffa45g/1/ check this i add more options which i want

Comment: This has ascending and descending: https://jsfiddle.net/jme11/g4ffa45g/2/.  I think the other that you modified wasn't saved.

Comment: This has corrected ascending and descending: jsfiddle.net/jme11/g4ffa45g/3.

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar can you guide me how can i install testing tools for angular js app karma,jamine and protractor ??

Comment: @NumanHassan how is that related to your question?

Comment: @Jossef Harush i  now want test my app but can't install these tools i post a q but no one answer then i ask from you guy by posting here in my old question

Answer (score 1):

## https://jsfiddle.net/rr6q0umb/1/

Add input for the direction

```
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="direction">Reverse</label>
```

Add to your `orderBy` filter the direction value (true for reverse)

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:sortBy:direction">
```

Comment: can you guide me how can i install testing tools for angular js app karma,jamine and protractor ??

Comment: i now want test my app but can't install these tools i post a q but no one answer then i ask from you guy by posting here in my old question