# include the form result into the 'sort by book title' result

Tags: arrays, angularjs, sorting, object, filter

There is a form in which the user can fill in, to search for a book, the result of the book will then be populated on the page. However I am not able to sort that particular book. Do you know how I can add the result of that book to the $scope.books object? Please see the code below: 
https://jsfiddle.net/dbxtcw9w/2
Thanks for your time!

```
<section id="App2" ng-app="form-input" ng-controller="ctrl">
<form id="form" ng-show="formDisplay" action="javascript:submit()" method="POST">  
  <summary> 
   <h5>Book Title:  </h5>
   <input type="text" name="title" ng-model="title" class="unique" placeholder="Enter Book Title" ></input> 
   <h5>Author:</h5>
   <input type="text" name="author" ng-model="author" class="unique" name="email" class='required' placeholder="Enter Author"></input> 
   <br>
   <button class="btn-md btn-info" style="margin-top:30px;" ng-click="submit()" >Submit</button>  
  </summary>
 </form> 
 <section class="row" id="user-input" ng-show="bookResult" style="margin-top:15px;"> 
 <summary class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">  
   <div style="background-color:white; ">
     <h2> {{title}}</h2>
     <h4 style="color:grey;">By <span ng-bind="author"></span></h4> 
     <hr>
     <h5>FREE SAMPLE <span class="review" onclick="review(this)">REVIEW</span></h5>
    </div> 
  </summary>
</section>
<summary class="row book-component">
 <div  ng-repeat='x in books | orderBy: order' class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" >
   <img class="thumbnail-image" > 
     <div> 
        <h2 ng-bind="x.title" class="title"></h2>
        <h4 ng-bind="x.author" class="author" style="color:grey;"></h4>
        <hr>
        <h5>FREE SAMPLE <span class="review" onclick="review(this)">REVIEW</span></h5>
     </div> 
 </div>
</summary> 
<button style="margin-top:30px" class="btn-lg btn-success" ng-click="changeOrder('title')">Sort by book title</button>
</section> 
<script>
    var app2 = angular.module('form-input', []);
    app2.controller('ctrl', function($scope) { 
    $scope.formDisplay=true;       
    $scope.bookResult=false;
    $scope.order = 'author';
    $scope.books=[
      {title:'Jani',author:'Norway'},
      {title:'Hege',author:'Sweden'} 
     ];       
    $scope.changeOrder = function (order) {
    $scope.order = order;
    };

    $scope.submit = function(){ 
          $scope.formDisplay = false; 
          $scope.bookResult = true;
    }
   });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.submit = function(){
  $scope.books.push(
    {
      title: $scope.title,
      author: $scope.author
    }
  );
};
```

Right now you have a special flow set up to support adding a single new book. In the view it looks like its being added to the array but it isn't. You need to create a new 'book' object using the user's input, then push it onto the $scope.books array. Since angular has 2 way data binding, pushing it onto the scope array (the model) will make it automatically appear in the view. It will also now be able to be sorted.

You'll note that you'll now be able to add as many new books to the list as you want.

Comment: Thanks. it works! I tried to put all the script code in external js file, but the ng-app angular js part does not work. Do you know how it works?

Comment: You should post a new question with your code so that I or someone else can assist you per stack overflow rules.